# Dropbox authentication within application

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication, dropbox

Is there any way to authenticate the user within the app for Dropbox in iPhone ?

I using [Dropbox IOS](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/authentication#ios) instruction for integrating Dropbox.

But my application got rejected by apple as "the app exits to Safari in order to authenticate the user's Dropbox account".

Please give me some solution so I can authenticate Dropbox within application.

Comment: you might have used older SDK version, so try using new one..https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-ios-sdk-1.3.2.zip

Comment: How can you get rejected for this!?!? This is actually the recommended (safer) way to get an OAuth token. . eg Facebook still uses this approach (albeit if the app is not installed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes you can authenticate dropbox within the application.The new API of dropbox authenticates within the app.

Below method is when you want to open dropbox.so just write that method and assign that action to button, and rest of the delegate methos you can find on https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/authentication#ios link

```
  -(IBAction)goDropBox
  {

  //DBSession* dbSession =    [[DBSession sharedSession] unlinkAll];
 // if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked])
  // {
       [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
  // }
  }
```

Happy Coding!!!!!!